# Merge LinkedList and Sort using Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am building a project in which I want to generate several linkedlist in parallel, then merge them and at last want to sort it using multithreading. I have created linkedlists in parallel. Actually I am not sure it is generated sequentially or parallelly. Can anyone help me in solving the problem.

My code is:

```
public class ParallelMaximizer {

int numThreads;
Random r = new Random();
int Low = 10;
int High = 100;
int numElements = 10;

static ParallelMaximizerWorker[] workers;
public ParallelMaximizer(int numThreads) {
    workers = new ParallelMaximizerWorker[numThreads];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numThreads = 4;
    ParallelMaximizer maximizer = new ParallelMaximizer(numThreads);
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    try {
        System.out.println("Maximum Number -> " + maximizer.max(list));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int max(LinkedList<Integer> list) throws InterruptedException {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int j=0; j<workers.length; j++){
        for (int i=0; i<numElements; i++){ 
            int numValues = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
            list.add(numValues);
        }
        System.out.println("LinkedList -> " + list);
        for (int i=0; i < workers.length; i++) {
            workers[i] = new ParallelMaximizerWorker(list);
            workers[i].start();
        }

        for (int i=0; i<workers.length; i++){
            try {
                workers[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        list = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    for(ParallelMaximizerWorker pmw : workers){
        max = Math.max(max, pmw.partialMax);
    }
    return max;
}   
}
```

Other class is:

```
public class ParallelMaximizerWorker extends Thread {

protected LinkedList<Integer> list;
protected int partialMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // initialize to lowest value

public ParallelMaximizerWorker(LinkedList<Integer> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        int number;
        synchronized(list) {
            if (list.isEmpty())
                return; // list is empty
            number = list.remove();
        }
        partialMax = Math.max(number, partialMax);
    }
}

public int getPartialMax() {
    return partialMax;
}

}
```

Comment: It could just be me but I'm not sure exactly what you're doing here. It doesn't look like the code matches the description in your post. Where are the "several linked lists" you plan to merge and sort?

Comment: It is in the max method. list.add(numValues)

Comment: I saw that but you create a single list of random numbers and pass the same list to the threads which then remove numbers from it only ever holding one value (`partialMax`). Once the threads join you allocate a new list. You do that `workers.length` times. In any case, there seems to only be one list and it's not filled in parallel.

Comment: Ohh I see. What changes should I make to create the list in parallel?

Comment: Hard to say based on what I see but you could create the one list (synchronized) and let the threads fill their own *local* lists from the original (parallel) or let them create their own random lists (parallel). You'd still be able to track the max if you like. Either way, in the end you'll have `workers.length` lists which you can sort and merge in parallel or synchronously.

Comment: Right, let's take a step back here.  Why do you think you want to do this in parallel?